# QListWidget, display several rows

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a `QListWidget` with a fixed width. Consequently, when I add items, a horizontal scrollbar appears to scroll along the row. But I would like to have a new row created below the current row so that no horizontal scrollabr appears but only vertical scrollbar if needed.
I found a [post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26706-QListWidget-in-iconMode-with-only-1-row) on another forum where the person says that he has by default what I want, and wants a single row, but by default I have a single row.

So how to make QListWidget create several rows when its width is fixed? I tried with `isWrapping= true / false`, `flow=LeftToRight / TopToBottom` but no change. And I am in `iconMode`.
I also found some solutions which proposed to use `QTableWidget` but I am sure it's possible to do it with `QListWidget`.

Comment: Finally, step by step, I recreate a QListWidget (in Qt Designer), set flow to leftToRifht, isWrappingto true, and add items to it programmatically. All is fine (it is displayed like a table with several columns and rows) until in QtDesigner, I add a stylesheet to the Qlistwidget : QListWidget{background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);} And suddenly, surprisingly and what annoys me, with the same configurations, all the items appears in ONE column and several rows, as if I put flow=TopToBottom and isWrapping=false ?! Is it a bug?

Comment: So, I put again flow=LeftToRight and isWrapping=true, and I get what I want. Maybe I missed something in my code, which was creating the column style.